# R - Generating a matrix/function from a dataset to use in a contour plot

Tags: r, plot

I am new to contour plots in R and I am trying to create one to show changes in nutrient concentration with depth and salinity.

My dataset currently looks like this ([link](http://pastebin.com/AJ69n18W)):

```
> head(DF)
  salinity depth  silicon
1     32.9  0.00 3.872717
2     32.9  0.00 3.906963
3     32.9  0.00 3.872717
4     33.4  3.56 3.119292
5     33.5  3.56 3.076484
6     33.0  0.00 3.675799
```

What I would like is for depth to be on the y-axis, salinity on the x-axis and the silicon concentration to be displayed based on colour.

From what I have read, in order to create a contour plot I need to turn the data I currently have into a matrix (by creating a function?).

Is this something that can be achieved? I'm not sure if I am going about this completely the wrong way, but essentially what I would like is something like this (apologies for image quality):

[image: contour plot]

But with salinity instead of time and silicon concentration instead of temperature.

Thanks,

Kez

Copy-pastable data:

```
DF <- structure(list(salinity = c(32.9, 32.9, 32.9, 33.4, 33.5, 33, 
33, 33.2, 33.3, 33.1, 33.1, 33.1, 33.7, 33.7, 34, 34, 34, 33.6, 
34.3, 34.3, 34.8, 35.8, 34.7, 34.4, 34.3, 34.5, 34.4, 34.9, 34.9, 
34.9, 34.8, 35, 35, 36, 34.9, 35, 35.2, 35.1, 30.2, 33.4, 34.5, 
34.9, 33.4, 33.4, 35.1, 35.1, 34.6, 35.1, 34.43, 34.67, 34.67, 
34.96, 34.76, 35.11, 34.14, 34.97, 25.13, 35.16, 35.11, 35.11, 
35.11, 35.15), depth = c(0, 0, 0, 3.56, 3.56, 0, 0, 4.493, 4.493, 
0, 0, 0, 4.362, 4.362, 9.9, 9.9, 0, 0, 5.826, 5.826, 11.725, 
11.725, 11.725, 0, 0, 2.766, 2.766, 9.355, 9.355, 0, 0, 12.46, 
12.46, 12.46, 0, 0, 12.427, 12.427, 1.2, 3.6, 6.2, 11, 1.1, 1.1, 
4.2, 12.8, 6.9, 10.4, 1.16, 4.5, 4.5, 15.35, 1.13, 8.25, 17.92, 
1.05, 14.25, 20.54, 0.97, 0.97, 7.67, 19.6), silicon = c(3.872716895, 
3.90696347, 3.872716895, 3.119292237, 3.076484018, 3.675799087, 3.855593607, 
3.547374429, 3.299086758, 4.591894977, 4.566210046, 4.857305936, 2.759703196, 
2.5456621, 2.597031963, 2.126141553, 2.417237443, 2.331621005, 1.989155251, 
1.835045662, 1.946347032, 1.937785388, 1.526826484, 1.638127854, 1.929223744, 
1.698059361, 1.894977169, 1.312785388, 1.698059361, 1.329908676, 1.484018265, 
1.621004566, 1.175799087, 1.167237443, 1.218607306, 1.038812785, 1.552511416, 
1.141552511, 5.329861111, 1.684027778, 2.612847222, 1.840277778, 1.588541667, 
1.553819444, 2.682291667, 1.692708333, 1.111111111, 1.935763889, 0.815972222, 
1.197916667, 1.197916667, 1.796875, 1.258680556, 1.059027778, 1.25, 0.512152778, 
1.336805556, 1.284722222, 0.998263889, 0.928819444, 0.399305556, 1.814236111
  )), .Names = c("salinity", "depth", "silicon"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -62L))
```

EDIT: For anyone interested, with the help of Frank's post below I was able to create the following with my full data set:

[image]

Comment: Can you post what you have tried so far?

Comment: Hi, honestly I haven't been able to try a great deal. Currently my data is simply not fit to be plotted into a contour plot and I have no idea how to get it there!
I think what I need to do is construct a matrix of the silicon values based on the depth/salinity values.

Comment: The problem is silicon and salinity are different ranges (don't overlap)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `interp` function from the `akima` package to interpolate.  Otherwise, you have to determine how to deal with areas that have missing data.

```
library(akima)
s <- interp(DF$salinity, DF$depth, DF$silicon, duplicate="mean", 
       xo=seq(min(DF$salinity), max(DF$salinity), length=50),
       yo=seq(min(DF$depth), max(DF$depth), length=50))
# you can choose values other than length = 50.
# Note that I used duplicate = "mean", but you can pick your own way of handling duplicates
```

Then, there are a number of options for plotting, each with lots of room for customization.  Here are a few choices:

```
filled.contour(s, color = terrain.colors)

image(s, col=rainbow(60))

library(fields); image.plot(s)

library(ggplot2)
ggs <- data.frame(salinity = rep(s$x, each=length(s$x)), depth = s$y, silicon = as.vector(t(s$z)))
p <- ggplot(ggs, aes(salinity, depth, fill=silicon))
p + geom_raster() + scale_fill_continuous(low="green", high="red") + theme_bw()
```

[image][image][image][image]

Comment: This is utterly fantastic! Pretty much exactly what I was hoping to achieve. Thanks Frank!